# read data from file in assembly AT&T

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, att

I want to read data from a file in assembly AT&T but I don't really know where to start.
I haven't found a useful resource on internet.

My working environment info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 14 - 64 bit
CPU: Intel
GAS compiler
Assembly Sintax: AT&T
I'll assemble with: as -o hello.o hello.s
I'll link with: ld -o test hello.o
```

Comment: If you are doing this purely for educational purposes, you might as well cheat. (Hmm, that sounded more logical in my head. Oh well!) What I mean by that is, you should write the equivalent code in C and then request that the compiler generate a dump of the assembly code that it compiled to. Go through that assembly output and make sure you understand what it means. The laborious act of *hand-writing* the assembly is not the important part for educational purposes. No one writes this stuff in assembly anymore. The important part is *understanding what it means* and how it would be done.

Comment: Do you know how to do a system call? Do you know what system calls you need to use on x86 to write to a file?

Comment: @CodyGray: C code that makes system calls actually just calls glibc's wrappers.  You don't really get to see the arg-setup and `syscall` unless you write it yourself, or step into glibc's wrappers with a debugger.  (Or in 32bit code, same for `int 0x80` or `sysenter` in the vdso page exported from the kernel to implement the user-space side of the 32bit `sysenter` / `sysexit` dance.)  But I agree with the overall point: **learning the Unix system-call API is orthogonal with learning asm and the system call A*B*I.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up how to do systems programming on POSIX in C (`open`/`read`/`write`/etc.), then use the same system calls in your asm.  There's nothing special about asm for this, compared to just doing it in C.  (except that in C you'd be using the glibc wrappers instead of the `syscall` instruction directly.)

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links documenting how to make system calls from asm.